# How to get Sum of timestamp in oracle?

Tags: oracle, sum, timestamp, oracle10g, varchar

Unfortunately i have stored timestamp as varchar in the database,as following format as `07:53:39` now i want sum of that timestamp which i have stored as a varchar, i have written the following query to convert varchar into timestamp by removing the colons,now i want sum of this timestamp how i can get it ,

```
select TO_CHAR(to_timestamp(regexp_replace(ru.duration,'(*[[:punct:]])',''),'HH:MI:SS'),'HH:MI:SS') FROM RESOURCE_UTILIZATION RU WHERE RU.RESOURCE_NAME='AKSHAY ANPAT';
```

the following is output of the above query :

```
07:53:39
03:07:02
07:18:21
05:10:44
06:14:49
07:43:51
```

please help me to get sum of timestamp in above query.

Comment: What does it mean to sum a timestamp?  That doesn't make sense.  Perhaps you really mean that you want to consider each row as an interval from midnight on the day in question and you want to sum those intervals?

Comment: i don't want date part of the column i just want sum of hours:minutes:seconds(HH:MI:SS) which will give me total time utilize by the employee.

Comment: So you want the sum of the intervals between the timestamp and midnight on the same date?

Comment: @suhas Strange design. If you want the total time spent by an employee, all you need to do is find difference between `out_time` and `in_time` and then use `SUM` with `GROUP BY`. What is the significance of the timestamp that you have posted? Is it the in_time, out_time or what?

Comment: i have change my query little bit to extract date part of timestamp, now i have only HH:MI:SS as a output, and i want sum of this, actually `07:53:39` , represent that he work for 7 hours,53 minute,39 seconds on particular day, and so those are individual time spend by him on different days, and now i want sum of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you want to sum the interval between the timestamp and midnight on the day in question.  If you want to get an `interval day to second` as a result

```
with x as (
  select '01:23:45' val from dual union all
  select '02:15:30' from dual
)
select numtodsinterval( sum( to_date( val, 'hh24:mi:ss' ) - trunc( sysdate, 'MM' ) ), 'day' )
  from x
```

returns the interval `+000000000 03:39:15.000000000`.  You could also get a difference in days just by removing the `numtodsinterval` call

```
with x as (
  select '01:23:45' val from dual union all
  select '02:15:30' from dual
)
select sum( to_date( val, 'hh24:mi:ss' ) - trunc( sysdate, 'MM' ) )
  from x
```

Comment: `with x as (
select TO_CHAR(to_timestamp(regexp_replace(ru.duration,'(*[[:punct:]])',''),'HH:MI:SS'),'HH:MI:SS') as val FROM RESOURCE_UTILIZATION RU 
WHERE RU.RESOURCE_NAME='AKSHAY ANPAT' and ru.current_date_time between to_date('01/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') AND to_date('04/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY')
)
select numtodsinterval( sum( to_date( val, 'hh24:mi:ss' ) - trunc( sysdate, 'MM' ) ), 'day' )
from x;`